# What are the relations between Alternative, MonadPlus(LeftCatch) and MonadPlus(LeftDistributive)?

Tags: pl.programming-languages, functional-programming, haskell, monad, applicative

Following up [What’s an example of a Monad which is an Alternative but not a MonadPlus?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13122489/1333025):

**Assume $m$ is a monad. What are the relations betweem $m$ being an *Alternative*, a *MonadPlusCatch* and a *MonadPlusDistr*?** For each of the six possible pairs, I'd like to have either a proof that one implies another, or a counter-example that it doesn't.

(I'm using

- *MonadPlusCatch* to distinguish a *MonadPlus* that satisfies the *Left-Catch* rule:

  ```
  mplus (return a) b = return a
  ```
- *MonadPlusDistr* to distinguish a *MonadPlus* that satifies *Left-Distribution* rule:

  ```
  mplus a b >>= k = mplus (a >>= k) (b >>= k)
  ```

see [MonadPlus on HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/MonadPlus).)

---

My current knowledge + intuition is that:

1. *MonadPlusDist* $\rightarrow$ *Alternative* - **<strike>likely</strike> true** - <strike>it seems straightforward, I believe I have sketch of a proof, I'll check it and if it's correct, I'll post it</strike> AndrewC answered this part.
2. *Alternative* $\rightarrow$ *MonadPlusDist* - **false** - as AndrewC showed in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13124491/1333025): `Maybe` is an *Alternative*, but it's known it's not *MonadPlusDist* (it's *MonadPlusCatch*).
3. *MonadPlusCatch* $\rightarrow$ *Alternative* - **<strike>likely</strike> false** - I believe that `MaybeT (Either e)` (or basically anything `MaybeT m'`) should serve as a counterexample. The reason is that

   ```
   ((pure x) <|> g) <*> a =    -- LeftCatch
       (pure x) <*> a
   -- which in general cannot be equal to
   ((pure x) <*> a) <|> (g <*> a)
   ```

   again I'll check and post. (Interestingly, for just `Maybe` it's provable, because we can analyze if `a` is `Just something` or `Nothing` - see the aforementioned AndrewC's answer.)
4. *Alternative* $\rightarrow$ *MonadPlusCatch* - **<strike>likely</strike> false** - if we prove that *MonadPlusDist* $\rightarrow$ *Alternative* then `[]` will server as a counter-example. (Or we could explicitly prove *Alternative* laws for `[]`.)
5. *MonadPlusDist* $\rightarrow$ *MonadPlusCatch* - **false** - `[]` is a known counter-example.
6. *MonadPlusCatch* $\rightarrow$ *MonadPlusDist* - **false** - `Maybe` is a known counter-example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## *MonadPlusDist* $\rightarrow$ *Alternative* is true.

### Corollary: *Alternative* $\rightarrow$ *MonadPlusCatch* is false

(because as Petr Pudlák pointed out, `[]` is a counterexample - it doesn't satisfy *MonadPlusCatch* but does satisfy *MonadPlusDist*, hence *Applicative*)

### Assumed: MonadPlusDist Laws

```
-- (mplus,mzero) is a monoid
mzero >>= k = mzero`                             -- left identity >>=
(a `mplus` b) >>= k  =  (a >>=k) `mplus` (b>>=k) -- left dist mplus
```

### To prove: Alternative Laws

```
-- ((<|>),empty) is a monoid
(f <|> g) <*> a = (f <*> a) <|> (g <*> a) -- right dist <*>
empty <*> a = empty                       -- left identity <*>
f <$> (a <|> b) = (f <$> a) <|> (f <$> b) -- left dist <$>
f <$> empty = empty                       -- empty fmap
```

**`<*>` expansion lemma**
Assume we use the standard derivation of an applicative from a monad, namely `(<*>) = ap` and `pure = return`. Then

```
mf <*> mx = mf >>= \f -> mx >>= \x -> return (f x)
```

because

```
mf <*> mx = ap mf mx                                  -- premise
          = liftM2 id mf mx                           -- def(ap)
          = do { f <- mf; x <- mx; return (id f x) }  -- def(liftM2)
          = mf >>= \f -> mx >>= \x -> return (id f x) -- desugaring
          = mf >>= \f -> mx >>= \x -> return (f x)    -- def(id)
```

**`<$>` expansion lemma**
Assume we use the standard derivation of a functor from a monad, namely `(<$>) = liftM`. Then

```
f <$> mx = mx >>= return . f
```

because

```
f <$> mx = liftM f mx                    -- premise
         = do { x <- mx; return (f x) }  -- def(liftM)
         = mx >>= \x -> return (f x)     -- desugaring
         = mx >>= \x -> (return.f) x     -- def((.))
         = mx >>= return.f               -- eta-reduction
```

## Proof

Assume (`<+>`,`m0`) satisfy the MonadPlus laws. Trivially then it's a monoid.

### Right Dist `<*>`

I'll prove

```
(mf <+> mg) <*> ma = (mf <*> ma) <+> (mg <*> ma) -- right dist <*>
```

because it's easier on the notation.

```
(mf <+> mg) <*> ma = (mf <+> mg) >>= \forg -> mx >>= \x -> return (forg x) -- <*> expansion
                   =     (mf >>= \f_g -> mx >>= \x -> return (f_g x))
                     <+> (mg >>= \f_g -> mx >>= \x -> return (f_g x))      -- left dist mplus
                   = (mf <*> mx) <+> (mg <*> mx)                           -- <*> expansion
```

### Left Identity `<*>`

```
mzero <*> mx = mzero >>= \f -> mx >>= \x -> return (f x) -- <*> expansion
             = mzero                                     -- left identity >>=
```

as required.

### Left Dist `<$>`

```
f <$> (a <|> b) = (f <$> a) <|> (f <$> b) -- left dist <$>

f <$> (a <+> b) = (a <+> b) >>= return . f              -- <$> expansion
                = (a >>= return.f) <+> (b >>= return.f) -- left dist mplus
                = (f <$> a) <+> (f <$> b)               -- <$> expansion
```

### `empty fmap`

```
f <$> mzero = mzero >>= return.f   -- <$> expansion
            = mzero                -- left identity >>=
```

as required

Comment: Great. I even suspect that the left- laws are implied by the right- laws for any _Applicative_, but I have no proof so far. The intuition is that `f <$>` doesn't carry any idiomatic action, it's pure, so it might be possible to somehow "switch the sides".

Comment: @PetrPudlák Updated - finished proof and added your corollory about `[]`.

Comment: @PetrPudlák Do you think we should add a proof that `[]` satisfies _MonadPlusCatch?_ At the moment it's just an assertion on the HaskellWiki. `>>= k` is defined explicitly using `foldr ((++).k)`

Comment: I suppose you mean _MonadPlusDist_, don't you? I think we could, this would complete the proof of the corollary.

Comment: @PetrPudlák Oh yes I do sorry. Will do.

Answer (score 6):

### A counter-example for *MonadPlusCatch* $\rightarrow$ *Alternative*

Indeed it's `MaybeT Either`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (MaybeT (Either b) a) where
    showsPrec _ (MaybeT x) = shows x

main = print $
    let
        x = id :: Int -> Int
        g = MaybeT (Left "something")
        a = MaybeT (Right Nothing)
    -- print the left/right side of the left distribution law of Applicative:
    in ( ((return x) `mplus` g) `ap` a
       , ((return x) `ap` a) `mplus` (g `ap` a)
       )
```

The output is

```
(Right Nothing, Left "something")
```

which means that `MaybeT Either` fails the left distribution law of `Applicative`.

---

The reason is that

```
(return x `mplus` g) `ap` a
```

ignores `g` (due to *LeftCatch*) and evaluates just to

```
return x `ap` a
```

but this is different from what the other side evaluates to:

```
g `ap` a
```